# how to convert variable name into index string of object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

when I make a looping based on the content in the **form** of an input form
I'll take the *attribute name to be used as a selector element and object index array of data*, but **the index is the variable name**

> how to convert from a variable name to string index on an object array
>   of data?

it aims to make input in the form can be filled automatically from the object array of data

```js
var data = {
  id: "4",
  Model: "804",
  Description: "AXIAL SETTER,100MM, MAGNETIC BASE"
};

var names = [];

if ($('#form').length == 1) {
  $('#form :input').each(function() {
    names.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  $.each(names, function(key, value) {
    $('[name="' + value + '"]').val(data.value);
    //value should be change with name, 
    //for example  :
    // $('name="Description"').val(data.Description);

  });
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="Model" placeholder="Model Of product" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description Of product" />
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-save">save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you tried `jquery.loadJSON` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. real data derived from ajax response, but for ease of writing I created manually. as seen in the data variables

Comment: but my difficulty in understanding jquery variable name **"value"** into an **object array index** , for example "value" to be index "id" thus becoming **" data.id "** @Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to run twice over the same data. You could simply do this to fill your form:

```
var data = {
  id: "4",
  Model: "804",
  Description: "AXIAL SETTER,100MM, MAGNETIC BASE"
};

if ($('#form').length == 1) {
  $('#form :input').each(function() {
    if (typeof data[$(this).attr('name')] != 'undefined'){
        $(this).val(data[$(this).attr('name')]);
    }
  });

}
```

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/nfq22d9r/1/

The code runs through all the forms input fields, checks if a fields name is existent as a key in the data object and sets the fields value to the one in the data object, if the key was found

Comment: thank you @Stefan Dochow,  this is a more efficient way